# what should I use for android app development : Java or Python?

Tags: java, android, python-3.x

I am a beginner in Android development.
But confused b/w the two technologies python and java.

Comment: Go with the one you're more familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAVA is the main language used in android apps. You can create app using python as well, but I will recommend you to use java as it is more orthodox and you can find tutorial for that too.

Answer (score 0):

Java Without a Doubt.

The native language for Android Development is Java, So plan on going with Java

Answer (score 0):

I think you should prefer java. Read [this](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-a-better-option-writing-Android-apps-in-Python-or-in-Java) document.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to develop your app in Java, as it is native Android language. If you want to try write your app with Python, you can try Kivy: https://kivy.org/#home

Comment: Why you have unaccepted my answer? Newly accepted answer is equals or worse, than mine...

Answer (score 0):

Beside my suggest of using Java (native language for Android, as some already pointed out), I also recommend [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) for your projects and this nice [Tutorial](https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps--ud853) for your first steps.